# Min/Max Values of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max, min

I seem to be stuck on what seems to be a pretty basic assignment. I was wondering if anyone could possibly lead me to the right direction and explain to me what is wrong. I have created an array with premade values inserted. Now I have to get the min/max values of this array and display them as well. I keep getting these two errors

> ".java:126: error: method getMax in class HighArray cannot be applied to given types;"
>
> ".java:126: error: method getMin in class HighArray cannot be applied to given types;"

If anyone could possibly help me out and explain why this is, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
class HighArray
{
    private long[] a;
    private int nElems;

    public HighArray(int max)
    {
        a = new long[max];
        nElems = 0;
    }

   //Search Method 
    public boolean find(long searchKey)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)
            if(a[j] == searchKey)
                break;
        if(j == nElems)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    //Insert method     
    public void insert(long value)
    {
        a[nElems] = value;
        nElems++;
    }

    //Delete method        
    public boolean delete(long value)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)
            if( value == a[j] )
                break;
        if(j==nElems)
            return false;
        else
        {
            for(int k=j; k<nElems; k++)
                a[k] = a[k+1];
            nElems--;
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Display Array Contents 
    public void display()
    {
        for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)
            System.out.print(a[j] + " ");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    //Max Method 
    public static int getMax(int[] a)
    {
        int maxValue = a[0];
        for(int i=1;i < a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i] > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = a[i];
                System.out.print("The max value is" + a[i]);
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    //Min Method
    public static int getMin(int[] a)
    {
        int minValue = a[0];
        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = a[i];
                System.out.print("The min value is" + a[i]);
            }
        }
        return minValue;
    }
}

public class Assignment
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int maxSize = 100;
        HighArray arr = new HighArray(maxSize);
        arr.insert(77);
        arr.insert(99);
        arr.insert(44);
        arr.insert(55);
        arr.insert(-22);
        arr.insert(88);
        arr.insert(-11);
        arr.insert(00);
        arr.insert(66);
        arr.insert(-33);

        arr.display();
        arr.getMax();
        arr.getMin();

        int searchKey = 35;
        if( arr.find(searchKey) )
            System.out.println("Found" + searchKey);
        else
            System.out.println("Can't Find " + searchKey);

        arr.delete(00);
        arr.delete(55);
        arr.delete(99);

        arr.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for future reference: Next time try to post only the relevant code segments. Copy-pasting the entire code is often impractical and won't get you a quick answer.

Comment: implement non-static versions of `max` & `min`, compatible with `long[]` instead of `int[]`, in your class, and it'll work OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods:

- `public static int getMax(int[] a)` and
- `public static int getMin(int[] a)`

have `int[]` as their input parameter,
but they are later called without any parameters: `arr.getMax();` and `arr.getMin();`.

This is the cause of the error you are getting from the compiler.

EDIT:

You probably want to modify your methods not to be *static* and not to have any input parameters (the array `a` would be used directly from the object and not passed to the method), so you can use methods on the object of the class like this: `arr.getMax();`.

To do so change the code in the following way:

- `public static int getMax(int[] a)` --> `public long getMax()`
- `public static int getMin(int[] a)` --> `public long getMin()`

** Note: The return type of `getMax` and `getMin` methods is changed from `int` to `long`, because `long`is the type of array in the `HighArray` class.*

Comment: You also need to change `int` to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable shadowing is the problem.

```
public static int getMax(int[] a) // <-- this a is different than the other one 
  {  
  int maxValue = a[0];
```

So,

1. you really don't need the parameter
2. your array has long values, not int values
3. The method shouldn't be static

Code

```
public long getMax() 
  {  
  long maxValue = a[0];
```

Same for min

Comment: I took your suggestion and changed the code up. Now my problem is it loops the min multiple times when I only need one min.                                        "77 99 44 55 22 88 -11 0 66 33  
The max value is 99
The min value is 44
The min value is 22
The min value is -11
Can't Find 35
77 44 22 88 -11 66 33  
"

Comment: Sorry that looks terrible to read haha. I didn't realize you couldn't hit enter to add space.

Comment: Your print statement is inside the for loop... What exactly did you expect to happen?

Comment: Yeah just noticed that, for some reason I didn't realize or think about that when coding.

Comment: @WilliamClarke A `get` method shouldn't print anything, so I assumed those were for debugging, so you could see progress as it searched for the min/max values. Last print is the result. If you want to just print the result, you shouldn't do it in the `getXxx` method, but in the `main` method, e.g. `System.out.print("The max value is " + arr.getMax());`. I mean, the method has a return value for a reason, right?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! I had just changed it to that before you commented haha. I appreciate that response

Comment: @WilliamClarke Remember to click the up-arrow on any answer you find useful, and to accept the best answer (from your point of view) by clicking the checkmark, so others can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction. --- Welcome to StackOverflow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change you getMin and getMax method.

It should also not be static otherwise you can't access the value array in that method.
Also your array is of type long so the return value should be long too.

```
    // Max Method

public long getMax() {
    long maxValue = a[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {

        if (a[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = a[i];
            System.out.println("The max value is" + a[i]);

        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

// Min Method

public  long getMin() {
    long minValue = a[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {

        if (a[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = a[i];
            System.out.println("The min value is" + a[i]);
        }
    }

    return minValue;
}
```